# mysql - select on few exact values

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database with such structure:

```
obj_id - rel_val
4034 - 7366
4034 - 7387
4035 - 7366
4035 - 8051
4035 - 8057
```

Field "obj_id" - it's item id field. Field "rel_val" - property value id.
For example. Item T-shirt with id 4034. There is set property color "red" with id 7366. And property size - "M"(id of this property value - 7387).

How i should write correct sql query to get all items with color "red" AND size "M" AND other something more.

What i have now:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT obj_id 
FROM cms3_object_content WHERE rel_val IN ('7343','7355','7368') LIMIT 100");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

I tried use operator IN, but it's return obj_id if any value mathces.

P.S. Sorry, for my bad english. I hope it's understanding what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT obj_id 
FROM cms3_object_content 
WHERE rel_val IN ('7343','7355','7368') 
group by obj_id 
having count(distinct rel_val) = 3
LIMIT 100
```